# Is it possible to use compositor when baking?

Tags: compositing-nodes, baking

I am using the compositor to add fog effect to a scene I want to use for a skybox. To create the skybox texture, it is possible to render six planes separately (set camera to 1:1 aspect ratio 90 deg fov), but that is a lot of work. Or maybe there is another way to fade out distant objects.

Comment: If you are in cycles perhaps use actual geometry with a volumetric material to make the fog and simulate distance fading?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Good point, but I always get the scene to dark, and it increases the render time alot.

Comment: If it is too dark then it's probably because it is too dense, never really tried it myself, but for fog I think it has to have really low density value. As for render times not really much one can do, maybe exclude fog effects from everything except camera visibility.